# Will setting gunicorn task setting to production mode mean that django will not run in DEBUG mode?

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn

I have a gunicorn task running on my django application.

The file looks like this:

`environment=IS_PRODUCTION="true",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="fn_django.settings.staging"`

In my settings file though, I have set DEBUG=false. Will my django application run in DEBUG mode as a result of what I wrote in my gunicorn settings file?